# How to include a call to a file in PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email

I have the following function for sending an email:

```
function send_email($email){
        $subject = "TITLE";

        $message = "HERE IS THE MESSAGE";

        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From: <emaily>' . "\r\n";

        mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
```

Instead of `$message` being a string, I want to call in the file `email.html` which holds my template.

I have added this:

```
require 'email.html';
```

But how can I call in the file?

$message = [call in email.html here]

Comment: no u need to use file_get_contents() to read the content and put them in the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Require is used when you want to call functions within another php file, or when you want to include some data to an HTTP response.

For this problem, `file_get_contents('email.html')` is the preferred option. This would be the method I would use:

```
function send_email($email){
    $subject = "Subject of your email";

    $message = "";
    if(file_exists("email_template.html")){
        $message = file_get_contents('email_template.html');
        $parts_to_mod = array("part1", "part2");
        $replace_with = array($value1, $value2);
        for($i=0; $i<count($parts_to_mod); $i++){
            $message = str_replace($parts_to_mod[$i], $replace_with[$i], $message);
        }
    }else{
        $message = "Some Default Message"; 
        /* this likely won't ever be called, but it's good to have error handling */
    }

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <doNotReply@myDomain.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: <$email>\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: doNotReply@myDomain.com\r\n";

    mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

I modified your code a little bit and added in both the `file_get_contents` and `file_exists`. `file_exists` confirms that the file is there. If it's not, it avoids the potential error from trying to read it in and can be changed to use some default. My next addition was a for loop. In the `$parts_to_mod` array, enter in the default values from the template that need to be replaced. In the `$replace_with` array, put in the unique values that you want to replace parts of the template with.

As an example where I use this, I have a template URL for one of my programs that says `id=IDENTIFIER&hash=THEHASH` so in my program, my `parts_to_mod` says `$parts_to_mod = array("IDENTIFIER", "THEHASH");` and my `replace_with` says `$replace_with = array($theUsersIdentifier, $theUsersHash);`. It then enters the for-loop and replaces the those values in `parts_to_modify` with the values in `replace_with`.

Simple concepts and they make your code much shorter and easier to maintain.

**Edit:**

Here is some sample code:

Let's the say the template is:

```
<span>Dear PUTNAMEHERE,</span><br>
<div>PUTMESSAGEHERE</div>
<div>Sincerely,<br>PUTSENDERHERE</div>
```

So, in your php code you'd say:

```
$parts_to_mod = array("PUTNAMEHERE", "PUTMESSAGEHERE", "PUTSENDERHERE");
$replace_with = array($name, $theBodyOfYourEmail,  $whoYouAre);
```

Comment: This is fantastic thank you. I have a question, if I wanted to include another parameter $name and then output this into the email, how would I do that with this? Would I need to pass the variable to the email.html file first?

Comment: I assume you mean saying something along the lines of "Dear $name". In such a case, I'll add some example code!

Comment: @Francesca If this is the best answer in your opinion, then a vote up and answer acceptance is always appreciated as my reputation could use some assistance ;)

Comment: Spencer +1 for you time, effort and quality answer.. This should have been voted far better than how it already is.

Answer (score 2):

just use `file_get_contents('email.html')` This method returns a string with the file contents

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to call custom email template.

```
function email($fields = array(),$name_file, $from, $to) {         
  if(!empty($name_file)) {             
    $mail_tem_path = 'templates/mails/mail--'.$name_file.'.php'; //change path of files and type file.
    if(file_exists($mail_tem_path)) {
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0". "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8". "\r\n";
      // Additional headers
      $headers .= "From:".$fields["subject_from"]." <$from>". "\r\n";  
      $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit". "\r\n";
      $message = file_get_contents($mail_tem_path);
      $message = preg_replace("/\"/", "'", $message);
      foreach ($fields as $field) {
       // Replace the % with the actual information  
       $message = str_replace('%'.$field["name"].'%', $field["value"], $message);
      }
      $send = mail($to, $fields["subject"], $message, $headers);
    } else {
      $send = mail($to, "Error read mail template", "Contact with admin to repair this action.");
    }
  } else {
    $send = mail($to, "Error no exist mail template", "Contact with admin to repair this action.");
  }
  return $send;  
}
```

Template html

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="/home">TODO write content %value_on_array%</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Array and execute function.

```
 $fields = array(
  "subject" => "tienda_seller_subject",
  "subject_from" => "tienda_email_subject_from",
  0 => array(
    "name" => "value_on_array",
    "value" => "result before change"
  ),                  
 );
 //email($fields = array(),$name_file, $from, $to);
 email($fields, 'admin', 'owner@email.com', 'client@email.com');
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzRZX.png)